# Conversion from Float to string in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

When you convert 12345678.0 (float) into string, I don't know why it displays me "1.234568E+07

I am using following code to display string

```
String FinalPayement;
float amount = 12345678.0;
FinalPayement = Amount.ToString();
```

Does anybody know?

Comment: We know a lot :) What do you want to know? How do you want your string to look?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you don't use `f` postfix for your literal, your literal will be `double` instead of `float`.

```
var amount = 12345678.0f; //amount will be float
var amount = 12345678.0; // amount will be double.
```

Second of all, C# is case-sensitive. That's mean `amount` and `Amount` are not the same. You should use `amount.ToString()` instead of `Amount.ToString()`.

Third of all, as a solution, you can use [*custom numeric format*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
float amount = 12345678.0f;
Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString(".0"));
```

Output will  be like below;

```
12345680.0
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/OUidCx)</kbd>.

Comment: (not downvoter) The question defines amount with float, not var. So it's not necessary to postfix with f.

Comment: @erikH You are wrong. You can't write `float amount = 12345678.0;`. It won't compile. It generates compile time error like `Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'float'; use an 'F' suffix to create a literal of this type`

Answer (score 0):

To exert control over the formatting, pass a format string to the overload of `ToString()` that accepts them. For instance:

```
float amount = 12345678.0f;
string finalPayment = amount.ToString("0.0");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String FinalPayement;
Decimal amount = 12345678.0;
FinalPayement = Amount.ToString();
```

instead of float try decimal... if you can change it then... otherwise other answers are quit good for you...

Answer (score 0):

```
float amount = 12345678.0f;
Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("f"));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
float.Parse("41.00027357629127", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

Comment: He wants to convert float to string (not string to float)